# Why am I getting a "unrecognized selector" error when I click on a button?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I click on any of the toobar buttons, I get a :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AddRecipientsTableViewController btnRemoteRecipients:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b87b10'

Header File

```
@interface AddRecipientsTableViewController : UITableViewController {

}

-(IBAction) btnLocalRecipients;
-(IBAction) btnRemoteRecipients;


@end
```

Interface File

```
#import "AddRecipientsTableViewController.h"


@implementation AddRecipientsTableViewController




-(IBAction) btnLocalRecipients{


}
-(IBAction) btnRemoteRecipients{


}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];







    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}



- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    self.navigationItem.title = @"Add Recipients";

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=NO;


    UIBarButtonItem            *localItem;
    UIBarButtonItem            *remoteItem;


    localItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Local"
                                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                  target: self
                                                  action: @selector( btnLocalRecipients: ) ];



    remoteItem = [[ UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithTitle: @"Remote"
                                                    style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                   target: self
                                                   action: @selector( btnRemoteRecipients: ) ];

    self.toolbarItems = nil ;

    self.toolbarItems = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects: localItem,remoteItem,nil ];

    [localItem release];
    [remoteItem release];


}

/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden=YES;


}

/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `:(id) sender` in the functions `btnLocalRecipients` and `btnRemoteRecipients`. 
Try with

```
-(IBAction) btnLocalRecipients:(id) sender{


}
-(IBAction) btnRemoteRecipients:(id) sender{


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `:` from your selectors. Your declared methods have no parameters, so there's no `:` in their name.

Answer (score 2):

The selector should be `btnRemoteRecipients` not `btnRemoteRecipients:` (remove the `:`)